# How to change my email in howtoforge.com?

Tags: forums

Unbelievable, but I cant find where change my email account at howtoforge.com. I'm right now wondering if that site ask me for an email address. Any idea of how to change my emails address on that web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the URL: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/usercp.php

You must scroll down a lot and look at left part of the screen to see the *User Control Panel* link.

That is what I call bad usability ;)

Answer (score 0):

Howtoforge has a new website, so it is easy to find now in your account details.

https://www.howtoforge.com/community/account/contact-details